# How to show EditText hint after .setText("")

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

Im trying to display the hint after I intentionally clear the edittext view. I tried the following code without success.

`etPhone.setText(null);
etPhone.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.phone_hint));`

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thx

Comment: Did you try to use both lines together?

Comment: set the ‘hint‘ on the xml layout and try

Comment: i resolve the problem set in and releasing the focus.